# Symmetric key creation with CKA_SENSITIVE false and CKA_PRIVATE as true

Tags: cryptography, aes, pkcs#11, hsm, symmetric-key

I am working on a cloud HSM service and I see `CKA_ATTRIBUTE_INVALID` error when I am trying to create a AES 256 key with following attributes:

```
CKA_TOKEN=0
CKA_SENSITIVE=0
CKA_PRIVATE=1
CKA_ENCRYPT=1
CKA_DECRYPT=1
CKA_SIGN=1
CKA_VERIFY=1
CKA_WRAP=1
CKA_UNWRAP=1
CKA_DERIVE=1
CKA_EXTRACTABLE=1
CKA_MODIFIABLE=0
```

and hence the error:
Status: `C_DeriveKey` returned error. (`CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID`)

I figured out if I pass `CKA_SENSITIVE` and `CKA_PRIVATE` both as 1 it passes and key gets created.

My question is how do I know which are the valid attribute combinations?
Can someone point me to a documentation, please.
I didn't find much details in standard `PKCS#11` spec guide.

I would appreciate any help here!!

Cheers.

Comment: Generally a key cannot be "private" if a regular user can simply copy the value using just the user PIN as authentication (i.e. when the key is not "sensitive"). However, many of these combinations are HSM specific, and it may even matter in which mode they are configured for (with FIPS mode generally the most strict mode).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes In context of PKCS#11 "private" is mean that the object can be found without authentication to token. It's usage may require future authentication.

Comment: Ah, yes, late night brain fart. Still, not being found and readable would be a strange combination.

Comment: Agree that it is strange. But it is valid combination.

Comment: Thank you @MaartenBodewes do we have any standard pkcs11 spec which may tell us the right combo of attributes?

Comment: @Zach Which HSM are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the following attributes are have wrong values:

```
CKA_SIGN=1
CKA_VERIFY=1
```

Symmetric key can't be used in signing.

Also this values are have some questions:

```
CKA_TOKEN=0
```

means that the key is session object,

```
CKA_SENSITIVE=0
```

means that the key value is "visible" - it is not secure.

From my experience:
try to remove attributes from template one by one and you can find which of them are wrong.

Comment: Symmetric keys can be used in "signing" as the `CKA_SIGN` attribute is also used for MAC operation. Indeed `CKA_TOKEN` is false but that's just the choice of the user. The description of `CKA_SENSITIVE` is of course correct.

Comment: `CKA_SIGN = 1` affects only methods `C_SIgn` & Co.     
MAC is not pure signature process.

Comment: I did a little search and it seems that e.g. IBM HSM's require sign to be present to use HMAC. Besides that, there is no need for CKA_SIGN to be present at all for secret keys unless a MAC is meant.

Comment: @Alexander thank you, it only works if i keep  CKA_SENSITIVE and CKA_PRIVATE both as 1 it passes and key gets created.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote / accept if the answer helped you solve your problem. Best way to say "thanks".